# FIRDatabaseReference observe gets empty updates while another reference is running a transaction

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-swift

We're using Firebase DB together with RxSwift and are running into problems with transactions. I don't think they're related to the combination with RxSwift but that's our context.

Im observing a data in Firebase DB for any value changes:

```
let child = dbReference.child(uniqueId)
let dbObserverHandle = child.observe(.value, with: { snapshot -> () in
    guard snapshot.exists() else {
        log.error("empty snapshot - child not found in database")
        observer.onError(FirebaseDatabaseConsumerError(type: .notFound))
        return
    }

    //more checks
    ...

    //read the data into our object
    ...

    //finally send the object as Rx event
    observer.onNext(parsedObject)
}, withCancel: { _ in
    log.error("could not read from database")
    observer.onError(FirebaseDatabaseConsumerError(type: .databaseFailure))
})
```

No problems with this alone. Data is read and observed without any problems. Changes in data are propagated as they should.

Problems occur as soon as another part of the application modifies the data that is observer with a transaction:

```
dbReference.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
    log.debug("begin transaction to modify the observed data")

    guard var ourData = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
        //seems to be nil data because data is not available yet, retry as stated in the transaction example https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }
    ...            
    //read and modify data during the transaction
    ...

    log.debug("complete transaction")

    return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
}) { error, committed, _ in
    if committed {
        log.debug("transaction commited")
        observer(.completed)
    } else {
        let error = error ?? FirebaseDatabaseConsumerError(type: .databaseFailure)
        log.error("transaction failed - \(error)")
        observer(.error(error))
    }
}
```

The transaction receives nil data at first try (which is something you should be able to handle. We just just call 
`return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)`
in that case.
But this is propagated to the observer described above. The observer runs into the "empty snapshot - child not found in database" case because it receives an empty snapshot.

The transaction is run again, updates the data and commits successfully. And the observer receives another update with the updated data and everything is fine again.

My questions:
Is there any better way to handle the nil-data during the transaction than writing it to the database with `FIRTransactionResult.success`
This seems to be the only way to complete this transaction run and trigger a re-run with fresh data but maybe I'm missing something-
Why are we receiving the empty currentData at all? The data is obviously there because it's observed.
The transactions seem to be unusable with that behavior if it triggers a 'temporary delete' to all observers of that data.

**Update**

Gave up and restructured the data to get rid of the necessity to use transactions. With a different datastructure we were able to update the dataset concurrently without risking data corruption.